# How to create a common title in X and Y axis in an arrange of plots using `ggdraw` and `plot_grid()` in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an arrange of plots for which I would like to create a common X-axe title and a common Y-axe title. As an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(ggpubr)z
theme_set(theme_cowplot())

df <- data.frame(x = 1:12, y = (1:12)^2)
df$grp = c('Some', 'Things', 'In a legend')

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color=grp)) + geom_point()
leg <- get_legend(p)
leg <- as_ggplot(leg)
p = p + theme(legend.position = "none")

plot_grid(
  p, p, leg, 
  p, p, leg,
  ncol = 3, rel_widths=c(2,2,1)
)
```

[image]

After some reading, I found as an option the use of `ggdraw`. However, I don't know how it works well, and I don't figure out how to get what I want (one `Y` in the y-axis and one `X` in the x-axis). Below is what I tried:

- I did the same than before but I removed also X and Y-axis titles for each plot

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:12, y = (1:12)^2)
df$grp = c('Some', 'Things', 'In a legend')

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color=grp)) + geom_point()
leg <- get_legend(p)
leg <- as_ggplot(leg)
p = p + theme(legend.position = "none",axis.title.x =element_blank(),axis.title.y =element_blank()) # I remove x and y titles for the plots

P <-plot_grid(
  p, p, leg, 
  p, p, leg,
  ncol = 3, rel_widths=c(2,2,1)
)
P
```

- Then, using `ggdraw`, I created an arrange of plots with one x-axis title in my desired position. However, I don't know how to get the same for the y-axe. I don't know how to increase the y-axe margin to add a label. Below is the code I tried so far:

```
P1 <- ggdraw(add_sub(P , "X", vpadding=grid::unit(0.8,"lines"), # With `0.8` I add some space in the X margin.
y=2, x=1, vjust=1, # With `y` and `x` I can indicate the coordinates for my desired text
angle=0) # With this I can change the orientation of the text
)
P1
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to create a common x and y-axis using `ggdraw` or with another function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to play around with the margins before `add_sub`:

```r
P <-plot_grid(
 p, p, leg, 
 p, p, leg,
 ncol = 3, rel_widths=c(2,2,1)
) + theme(plot.margin = margin(30, 30, -50, 50))

P <- add_sub(P, "x axis text", hjust = 1)
P <- add_sub(P, "y axis text", -0.05, 5, angle = 90)
ggdraw(P)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron, I didn't think about that!

Comment: One doubt, why the legends do not appear in your plot?

Comment: Hi again @Allan Cameron, Can I ask you something? Why do you use `-50` as one of your margins? When I use that I lose part of my last row of plots. Is that a mistake? Another thing is that I don't know how exactly move `y axis text` and `x axis text` within the plot. I have tried changing some numbers in your code but in my real case it doesn't work. Could you explaining what the numbers you use do? What are they for?

Comment: @Dekike the calls to `add_sub` seemed to push the plots upwards from below, so the negative lower margin was to compensate for that. The left and right margins were to create space for the y axis title and the legends. In the calls to `add_sum`, there are x and y values after the labels, but I have left the defaults for the "x axis text" label.  Try adding x=0.2 after "x axis text" and you will see it moves to the left. x = 0.8 moves it to the right (the default is 0.5 which is the middle of the plotting window.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Ylab<-ggplot()+
    geom_text(aes(x=0,y=0),label="Ylab",size=5,angle=90)+
    theme_void()

    legend<-get_legend(p)

    fig<-plot_grid(p,p,p,p,nrow=2)

    plot_grid(Ylab,fig,legend,nrow=1,rel_widths = c(0.02,1, 0.1))
```

You can plot the ylab separately as with geom_text.